# Fedora 30/31 live USB stick does not boot completely

Tags: boot, usb, installation, fedora

I recently purchased a new Dell Latitude laptop, on which I want to install Fedora Linux. This should be a fifteen minutes job, but now it fails on many places.

I tried first UnetBootin, but the resulting USB didn't even get recognized by the BIOS to boot from. Using Rufus, Fedora 31 gave a syslinux version issue, although that did boot. It just stopped after a while though.

The furthest I have gotten until now was to use Rufus and the Fedora 30 Workstation Live ISO. It gets recognized by the BIOS as bootable and it boots. Kind of. It gets stuck at a dracut job that waits forever.

I never had this much trouble installing any Linux on a PC (even Slackware from floppies was easier). Am I missing something here? What could I try more to get Fedora on that laptop?

Comment: I've read that some of the latest kernel versions have an issue with some Dell TPM/PTT modules.  If you disable TPM/PTT in your BIOS, can you boot/install then?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I found TPM, switched the "On" button off, but no real effect. Have not found anything like "PTT".

Comment: Sorry, I've just been updating Fedora as my version goes EOL.  I haven't done a fresh install in quite a while.  Have you tried the [Fedora Media Writer](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/install-guide/install/Preparing_for_Installation/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As noted in a comment, please use [Fedora Media Writer](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/install-guide/install/Preparing_for_Installation/#_fedora_media_writer) — this is our tested and supported media creation tool.
2. 99% of the time when I've had a problem like this, the issue was with the USB drive. If you're just copying a few files back and forth, you may not notice problems, but for the install media, one little misplaced bit can mess the whole thing up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with another USB drive and it worked. Have the problem now that Fedora 30 Live does not see the PCIe SSD drive. Will try with F31.